# Removing Preload Div and JS breaks website

Tags: javascript, html, css, preloader

I created a site with a preloader and when I was done decided I no longer want it, but when I remove the code for it, it won't load past it any longer. It just displays a grey box when attempting to access the website.

There's quite a lot of code to show, but I was just hoping someone may be able to steer me in the right direction by telling me what Div is causing this via inspect element.

If there's any snippets of code I can provide please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#main` id on the upper most div is causing the problem. Consider using semantic elements like `main` over generic divs.

[image]

Comment: Or simply remove the `opacity: 0` from `#main`

Comment: I have been ripping my hair out, thank you so much!